# How to restart a counter in a program using a push button in a LDR Tripwire setup

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, button, photoresistor

So, trying to configure this code so that when I push the button, the person counter will go to zero and just as it goes, the counter will increase when the LDR will get tripped and again when the button is pressed, the counter will go to 0.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int laser=8;
int pushbutton=12;
int flag=0; 
int myCounter = 0; 
LiquidCrystal lcd(7,6,5,4,3); 

void setup() 
{ 
    pinMode(laser,OUTPUT); pinMode(pushbutton,INPUT); 
    lcd.begin(16, 2); 
    lcd.print("Person Counter:"); lcd.setCursor(0,1); 
    lcd.print(0); 
} 

void loop() 
{
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    digitalWrite(laser,HIGH); 

    if(analogRead(A0) < 600) //A0= LDR
    {
        flag = 1;
    } 

    if(analogRead(A0) > 600 && flag == 1) 
    {
        myCounter++; 
        delay(200); 
        lcd.print(myCounter); 
        delay(20); 
        flag=0;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code. I made some modification and also comment out that things.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 6, 5, 4, 3);

int laser = 8;
int pushbutton = 12;
int flag = 0; 
int myCounter = 0; 

void setup() 
{ 
  pinMode(laser,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pushbutton,INPUT_PULLUP); // Provide pull-up

  lcd.begin(16, 2); 
  lcd.print("Person Counter:");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1); 
  lcd.print(0); 
} 

void loop() 
{
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  digitalWrite(laser,HIGH); 

  if(analogRead(A0) < 600) //A0= LDR
  {
    flag = 1;
  } 

  if(analogRead(A0) > 600 && flag == 1) 
  {
    myCounter++; 
    delay(200); 
    lcd.print(myCounter); 
    delay(20); 
    flag = 0;
  }

  if(digitalRead(pushbutton) == LOW) // When button pressed
  {
    myCounter = 0; // Set counter to 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you.